# How can I rotate the camera using a Script Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Explaining about my problem:
**I was looking for a way to rotate the camera at angle depending when the player triggered an object** and what I was hoping is that to rotate the camera at any degree like 90, 40 , 30 or something like that.

What I tried/wrote  *Update*:
Which work but only in  the camera_follow script, it just rotate base on the player facing.

```
Transform.rotation = player.postion;
```

**________________________________________________________________________**

Vice versa it did the same thing only if you apply it to the camera_follow script

```
using UnityEngine;


public class rotate : MonoBehaviour{
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));

[SerializeField]
private Camera cam; //fill from editor

cam.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));

      }
         
  }

}
```

**________________________________________________________________________**

Which did the same thing only if you apply it to the camera_follow script

```
 using UnityEngine;


 public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
    {
    Transform camera;
    
       [SerializeField]
       private Camera cam = default;


  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
  {
      if (CompareTag("Player"))
      {
       
        cam.transform.Rotate(0, 10, 0);

     
      }
         
  }

}
```

which sort of work, when I apply it to the camera follow script.

This one gave an error because I didn't set to `camera cam = default;`

But after applying it, it still only work for the camera_follow script and if put it rotate script didn't work.

```
using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using UnityEngine;
        
    public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
    {
      Camera cam;
    
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
 {
     if (CompareTag("player")) 
     {
         transform.rotation.cam = 90;
     }

 }
```

*And the error it gave me:* `'Quaternion' does not contain a definition for 'cam' and no accessible extension method 'cam' accepting a first argument of type 'Quaternion' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1061)`

Then I tried using an camera > cube but that didn't work either. Basically I copied camera rotate script an instead camera I put GameObject cube `

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
  GameObject cube;

 
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
 {
     if (CompareTag("player")) 
     {
         transform.rotation.cube = 90;
     }

 }
```

which gave me the same error and then I search how to rotate camera in unity, but no luck because it was mostly about the mouse moving the camera on youtube, I tried google but it gave me 2 answers: Unity has a Quad primitive game object that you can make by: GameObject > Create Other > Quad.
...
Then you can have this logic in a script attached to each Quad:

```
function Update() {
transform. rotation = Camera. main. transform. rotation;
}
```

was is mostly about vertical orientation which wasn't helpful with the problem I had  https://answers.unity.com/questions/772494/quaternian-rotation-to-face-camera.html

**,**

This one was just about the axis about the mouse and thats google said when I searched Unity camera rotate

```
using System. Collections;
public class CamRotation: MonoBehaviour {
public float rotationSpeed = 10;
void Update() {
Vector3 rotation = transform. eulerAngles;
rotation.x += Input.axis
transform.
}
```

and I tried looking at forms but didn't help either because it told me the same thing, that I should do this: V also I want clarify that that's all it said
**V**

```
 Vector3 rotation = transform.eulerAngles;
    rotation. x += Input. 
    transform.
```

Also I have a script setup to follow the player as shown:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera_follow : MonoBehaviour{ 
    
    public Transform Player;
    public Vector3 offset;

   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Player.position + offset;
       
    }
```

}

Short answer:
I want to know is how would I rotate the camera it when triggered

Vice versa It kept doing the thing only if I apply it to camera_follow script and then I came realize that these are basically the same transform.rotation

**_________________________________________________________________________**
**Update**

I found a solution to my problem sort-of, here's what I did:

So now I need to figure out how to stop the camera from rotating.

```
    [SerializeField]
       private Camera cam;


 public float rotationing = 0;
 public float positioning = 0; 

    void Update()
    {
        
    transform.Rotate(0, rotationing, 0 * Time.deltaTime);  
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, positioning , 0);

    }
}
```

**________________________________________________________________________**

Which works but it rotates the object/camera its attach to, so now I just need to figure out how to add a event system.

using UnityEngine;

```
public class rootate : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool rotateMe;



public void stooper()
{
  
 Invoke("stooper", 20f);    
     if (rotateMe) 
     {
         transform.Rotate(0, 10, 0);

     }

  
}

  public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
  {

    if (rotateMe)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10);
    }
         
  }

}
```

**_________________________________________________________________________**

**Updated** I've changed a few thing to see if it will work but sadly it didn't. Instead get component I tried if statement in the `void stooper()` then put another if statement in the `void triggerevent()`

```
 using UnityEngine;

public class rootate : MonoBehaviour
{

public bool rotateMe;



public void stooper()
{
  
 Invoke("stooper", 20f);    
     if (rotateMe) 
     {
         transform.Rotate(0, 10, 0);

     }

  
}

  public void OnTriggerEnter(Collision collision)
  {

    if (rotateMe)
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10);
    }
         
  }

}
```

**_______________________________________________________________________**

I've thought get component could help, but didn't it help either

```
  using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class mycamera : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
       private Camera cam = default;
    
    Transform Player;
    
        void Update()
        {
        
            if (CompareTag("CAM RT"))
            {
                GetComponent<rootate>();

            }   
        
        }
    }
```

**_________________________________________________________________________**

I've tried this two, from the unity documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html and I change few things to make  it work, but it basically did the same thing like the rest of the scripts

**What it said**

```
    using UnityEngine;
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    float rotationSpeed = 45;
    Vector3 currentEulerAngles;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X)) x = 1 - x;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Y)) y = 1 - y;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) z = 1 - z;

        //modifying the Vector3, based on input multiplied by speed and time
        currentEulerAngles += new Vector3(x, y, z) * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;

        //apply the change to the gameObject
        transform.eulerAngles = currentEulerAngles;
    }
```

**_______________________________________**

**What I did instead:**

```
using UnityEngine;
public class rootate : MonoBehaviour
{
    float rotation_Speed = 45;
    Vector3 currentEulerAngles;

    void Update()
    {
       
        currentEulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 10, 0) * Time.deltaTime * rotation_Speed;

        
        transform.eulerAngles = currentEulerAngles;
    }
```

I've left it as it was because I just wanna see if it would work or not but **"it sorta did"** it did the same thing as every script except I could control the speed which wasn't helpful either because it was just  too slow or fast

**_________________________________________________________________________**

**Update January 22/2021** I have event system which works but it won't rotate the Camera. Here's the video this script is based on:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gx0Lt4tCDE0&t=204s **skip to 2:47 if you don't wanna hear what event system is**

Here's the code, its 3 scripts: Event_ #1 that's the name of the script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Event_ : MonoBehaviour
{
 

  private void Awake()
  {
      Cam = this;
  }


   public static Event_ Cam;

  public event Action OnCameraTrigger;

  public void OntriggeredCamera()
  {
    if (OnCameraTrigger != null) 
    {
      transform.Rotate(0, 10 ,0);
    }
  }

}
```

**_________________________________________________________________________**
Trigger_area #2

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Triggered_area : MonoBehaviour
{
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
  {
      Event_.Cam.OntriggeredCamera();
  }
}
```

Which gave me an Error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Triggered_area.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/Camera event/Triggered_area.cs:9)
```

Because I've change something(whiched I've forgot what I changed) in the script or its just unity.
**_________________________________________________________________________**
What I've change:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Triggered_area : MonoBehaviour
{
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
  {
      Event_.Cam.OntriggeredCamera();
  }
}
```

Because it would give me this `error:warning CS0414: the field (9, 16):'Triggered_script.Camrotation' is never assigned but its value is never used` then I change back
**_________________________________________________________________________**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Event_ : MonoBehaviour
{
 
 private void Start()
 {
   StartCoroutine(event_timer());
 }

  private void Awake()
  {
      Cam = this;
  }


   public static Event_ Cam;

  public event Action OnCameraTrigger;

  public void OntriggeredCamera()
  {
    if (OnCameraTrigger != null) 
    {
      Debug.Log("Its not null, lull");
    }
  }
  
  
  public IEnumerator event_timer()
  {
     yield return(1f);
  }

}
```

I tried IEnumerator and it worked but it still wouldn't change the camera rotation.

**_______________________________________________________________________**
What else  I've  trying was: applying Event_ & Trigger_area > Cube,
Triggerd_script > camera,

**Note:**I've put `mycamera` script in `triggerd_script`               triggerd_script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Triggered_script : MonoBehaviour
{
 public Camera cam;
 
 [SerializeField]
 private float CamRotation = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Event_.Cam.OnCameraTrigger += Camrotate;
    }

    public void Camrotate()
    {
    Invoke("Camrotate", 10f);
    cam.transform.Rotate(0, 10, 100);
 
    }

}
```

so then I realized that it wasn't IEnumerator or invoke and thought it was that I had to change the `transform.Rotate(0, 10, 0);` to `cam.transform.rotate(0, 10, 0);` which didn't work and then added `public Camera cam;` which didn't rotate, so now I'm thinking has something to do with the event or I just need to add something
**_________________________________________________________________________**

Which just rotated the **"objects"** not the camera

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Triggered_area : MonoBehaviour
    {
      private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
      {
          Event_.Cam.OntriggeredCamera();
          transform.rotate(0, 10, 0);
      }
    }
```

**_________________________________________________________________________**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Event_ : MonoBehaviour
    {
     
     private void Start()
     {
       StartCoroutine(event_timer());
     }
    
      private void Awake()
      {
          Cam = this;
      }
    
    
       public static Event_ Cam;
    
      public event Action OnCameraTrigger;
    
      public void OntriggeredCamera()
      {
        if (OnCameraTrigger != null) 
        {
          transform.rotate(10, 10 , 0);
        }

 }


  public IEnumerator event_timer()
  {
     yield return(1f);
  }

}
```

This one just doesn't work when I applied transform.rotate(0, 10, 0);

**_________________________________________________________________________**

**Update January 25/2021**
Now I realized is that it needs to be `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()` not a custom `void Cam_rotate(){}` to make the function/method to make it work but it just rotates the speed and never stops, in the mean time I'll try to find a solution that will work or if anyone has a solution.

Note: the message it gave was:
**trying to Invoke method: Triggered_script.Camrotate couldn't be called.** it's doesn't say it's as a error but as message. I'll try to find the something to fixed the problem. I figured it out, I forgot that I had to change the name of the invoke string name it was set to. basically I forgot that when you changed the name of the void `void FixedUpdate(){invok("Camerarotate")}` to `FixedUpdate(){invok("FixedUpdate")}`
**__________________________________________________________________________**
February 8/2021 *Update* **Note: I realize that you can use the animation to move things instead of using a timer cause if you un-loop it and it will stay in place from last the last frame.**

I figured out how to reposition the camera so then I started trying a making cut-scene so it didn't just teleported to the location and as of now I have something in place which sorta works, here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggeredScript : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
 private Animator myanimation;


  private void Start()
  {
      Cam_Event.Ad.OnCameraTriggerEnter += TriggeredCameraEvent;
       
       myanimation = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }


    private void TriggeredCameraEvent()
    {
        transform.Rotate(-0, 0 , 0);
       transform.Translate(0, -10 , 0);

       if (CompareTag("Player"))
       {
          myanimation.Play("Base Layer.Cam_animation", 0 , 0, 0.12); 
       }

    }       
               
    }
```

What I did was put the animation in the parent of the camera not the camera because it would keep the camera in the same place and loop if you have it enabled.

When it's applied it'll pop up a box for (name of the script)Triggered Script (name of whatever method box)`Myanimation` > What ever you name the parent, what I expected was that I would play the camera animation and stop when it triggered the cube but it didn't because when I applied animation & `myanimation` under the same name it would it would just in the air stop if you don't have a state to stop the animation. if I just do `myanimation` not put in animator it wouldn't rotate because it would just say `'Rotate camera'` AnimationEvent `has no function name specified!`, Because of that it would've need be set on the animation to rotate it and now I'm in pickle with since can't apply Rotate Camera under both animator & `myanimation`.  I'll update more on the way once I or someone figure it out.

This is the image for the camera_follow:
[image: 1]

Comment: You would learn how c# works in general and then set `cam.transform.rotation = someValidQuaternionValue;` ...

Comment: It's pretty clear from this question that you haven't read the docs concerning `transform.rotation`.  If you checked them, you'd see that `transform.rotation` references a quaternion value, nothing that would have a `.cube` or `.cam` property. Maybe you mean to put those ahead of `transform.rotation`, like `cam.transform.rotation`, but either way you'd quickly realize your mistake if you read your error message and looked at the documentation.

Comment: maybe so maybe so

Comment: dude you just set the eulerAngles ... https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html

Comment: moreover, you rarely set the eulerAngles.  all you are looking for is **Rotate**.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: the code you're looking for is probably this simple, `transform.Rotate(0f, 90f, 0f);`

Comment: @Fattie that only work if set to the camera to that script

Comment: so that camera would need a second to make it work probably

Comment: @Fire-Source- - you should surely have a script on that camera. But, obviously it's trivial to go (in another script) myCamera. .. Rotate, etc.  Enjoy!

Comment: @Fattie I'll try that Out : )

Comment: @Fattie So now I just need to figure a way for the camera to stop rotating. No matter what I mostly I would just keep rotating so any thoughts?

Comment: note that the variables Rotating and Positioning **must** be lower case

Comment: normnally you'd have as variable `public bool doRotateMe` then the code would be like `if (doRotateMe) { .. your rotation code above }` try that and when it is running, you can literally set or not set the doRotateMe variable in the Inspector, as it is running !

Comment: @Fattie it works now I just need a timer so that it stops

Comment: howdy bud.  timers are extremely easy. you just go `Invoke("stopper", 5f)'`  that will run after five seconds.  don't forget the "f".  then you have a function  `public void stopper() { .. turn off the variable/whatever in here; }`  it's that easy champ.  note that it must be "public" (and "void")

Comment: lol good luck champ.  don't forget to put "Debug.Log("HELLO");" everywhere - for example in your "stopper" function - so that you know what is going on. it makes it much easier.  BTW you should also be using Translate https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html to move things, rather than just "setting the position".  it's much better in many ways

Comment: @Fattie I have a question   how Can I apply to a trigger a event that effect mycamera script?

Comment: @Fattie **Noted**..... I just need a trigger event to rotate to the camera. I've tried get component but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Jan 16/2020

Also I will make changes until further notice

I figure a solution to the problem in a sense that function probably but it won't stop rotating  here's code for what I did:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mycamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
   private Camera cam;


 public float Rotationing = 0;
 public float Positioning = 0; 

    void Update()
    {
        
    transform.Rotate(0, Rotationing, 0 * Time.deltaTime);  
    transform.position = new Vector3(0, Positioning , 0);

    }
}
```

**Update 2/16/21**

I found a better solution to the problem, by using animation to move the camera not transform, translate, invoke etc.Link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJiO4cvsHAo

all I had to do was this:

```
System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cammera_eevent2 : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private Animator Cam_controller = null;

[SerializeField] private bool Cammera_eevent = false;


[SerializeField] private bool Camer2 = false;


private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
  if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
  {
      if (Cammera_eevent)
      {
         Cam_controller.Play("Cammera_eevent", 0, 0f); 
         gameObject.SetActive(false);
      }  
      else if (Camer2)
      {
        Cam_controller.Play("Camer2", 0, 0f); 
         gameObject.SetActive(false);
      }
  }

}


}
```

**more info in the video**, the 2 `bool` are animation/clip. It will trigger the camera animation through the game object also create a parent put the camera in the parent then set animations in the parent instead of camera. Also put the `Camera_follow`* (whatever the name of the script is)

*script in **Main camera** not **parent of camera**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera_follow : MonoBehaviour{ 
    
    public Transform Player;
    public Vector3 offset;

   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Player.position + offset;
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rotation of your camera with [Quaternion.Euler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html)

If you want to set the rotation on the Y axis it would be:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));
```

On the other hand, ´transform.rotation´ refers to the transform of the gameobject the script is attached to. If the camera component is there in the same game object where you are setting the transform rotation it will rotate along, if it is not, you can drag it in to your script from wherever it is in the editor with:

```
[SerializeField]
private Camera cam; //fill from editor
```

and set its rotation with:

```
cam.gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));
```

So that you set the rotation of the transform of the gameobject where the camera is attached to.

Take into account that to fire the OnTriggerEnter you need trigger colliders in your game objects so that when the objects collide/intersect the event executes.

Comment: The access to `gameObject` is unnecessary overhead ;)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay now it's telling the cam is assigned even through I selected camera. the warning it gave was CS0649

Comment: I just don't get I don't understand what I'm missing exactly? am I missing a parent for the camera or a object to put the camera in or just typing it wrong.

Comment: you can assing it with `private Camera cam = default;` tu eliminate the warning. Google the warning to understand waht causes it and how to avoid it. As told, the camera is assigned by dragging it to the Serialized field in the editor, as compilator is not aware if its assigned in the editor or not, you need to inititalize the variable in the code to avoid the warining.

Comment: thanks @derHugo, it was for the question maker's understanding that the transform is in the gameobject. Yes, monobehaviour's transform can be accessed directly.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay now it works but if the player rotates then then the camera rotates that direction of where the player is facing

Comment: check the hierarchy, if you rotate a parent gameobject, all children rotate along with it

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I found another way which is transform.rotation = player.rotation or position;

Comment: @rustyBucketBay also also The reason why the script it didn't work for me, because the cam was set to player position and that's **"probably"** why it didn't work

Comment: **And I wanna thank for the people helping me, Thank you**

Comment: @rustyBucketBay the camera was set to **Player position** so theirs no parent just wanna clarify that

Comment: never set the rotataion and never use quaternions for any reason.  **simply set the euler angles** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I've  fix the problem sort of, what did is set as transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0));  and put it in the camera follow script which worked instead but not for camera rotation script Update

Comment: @Fire-Source - DON'T do that.  all your looking for is .eulerAngles or likely even simpler, .Rotate .  If you want to rotate something you use .. ..Rotate  :)

Comment: @Fattie ok also I added an image for context